# How to write a generic template for all basic_string instances

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I am trying to write a template like this.

```
template <char c,typename Options, 
   basic_string<class,class,class> Options::* member> 
   struct option_string;
```

However I keep getting a compilation error.
I would like to know how to write a template that takes three options: a `char`, any class and a pointer to a member of that class which must be a `basic_string` specialization.
I want to avoid writing a template for each specialization of `basic_string`.

My goal is to created a generic command line option library.
The following is how I would like to use it.

```
class Options : public Command_Line_Options_Parser<Options> {
public:
  int integer = 0;
  float real_number = 0.0;
  bool boolean = false;
  bool make_true = false;
  bool make_false = true;
  std::string string;
  typedef Options O;
  typedef Command_Line_Options<
            option_int<'i',&O::integer>,
            option_float<'f',&O::real_number>,
            option_bool<'b',&O::boolean>,
            option_true<'t',&O::make_true>,
            option_false<'t',&O::make_true>,
            option_string<'s',&O::string>
           >
  option_list;
};

int main(int argc,char**argv ) {

  Options options;

  options.parse(argc,argv);
  std::cout << "integer : " << options.integer <<endl;
  std::cout << "real_number : " << options.real_number <<endl;
  std::cout << "boolean : " << options.boolean <<endl;
  std::cout << "make_true : " << options.make_true <<endl;
  std::cout << "make_false : " << options.make_false <<endl;
  std::cout << "string : " << options.string <<endl;
};
```

I would prefer for `option_string` to accept all specializations of `basic_string` instead of just `std::string`.

Comment: I am getting a compile error with the following code

    template <char c,typename Options,basic_string<class,class,class> Options::* member> struct option_string;

Is there a way of writing a generic template that takes only three parameters. 
A char, a class name and a Pointer to a member in the class which of type basic_string

Comment: @user905927: Put that in your *question*, not a comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You won't get around having to specify the return type directly. And in that case, why bother with the `basic_string` class directly? Just take a `typename String` and be done:

```
template<char C, class Options, class String, String Options::* Member>
struct option_string;
```

And if you still want to make sure that `String` is indeed a specialization of `basic_string`, well, take this little helper and `static_assert` it:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>

template<class T>
struct is_basic_string : std::false_type{};

template<class Ch, class Tr, class Al>
struct is_basic_string<std::basic_string<Ch,Tr,Al>> : std::true_type{};

// in 'option_string'
static_assert(is_basic_string<String>::value,
    "Data member must be a 'basic_string' specialization.");
```

---

Since there doesn't seem to be a need to pass the member pointer as a template argument, I suggest just passing it in the constructor:

```
template<char C, class Option, class String>
struct option_string{
  static_assert(is_basic_string<String>::value,
      "Data member must be a 'basic_string' specialization.");
  typedef String Option::*member_type;

  option_string(member_type m, ...) : member(m), ... { ... }
private:
  member_type member;
};

template<char C, class Option, class String>
option_string<C, Option, String> make_option_string(String Option::*member, ...){
  return {member, ...};
}

// in code:
auto os = make_option_string<'H'>(&some_type::a_string_member);
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid that.
I want to know if it is possible to avoid giving the type

Comment: @user905927: Not if you want to pass the member pointer as a template argument (there is no deduction for non-type parameters). Do you really need to do that?

Comment: Do I need to no.
However I would prefer not repeat types if I do not need to.

Comment: @user905927: Well, then just pass it in the constructor, where you can have argument deduction. And then use a `make_option_string` function together with `auto` to not have to mention the string or option type.

Comment: I am sorry I do not follow.
The constructor of which class Options?

Comment: @user905927: The question of *do you really need to do that?* refers to do you really need to *pass the member pointer as a template argument*? Rather than *do you really need to avoid passing the type*. The reason is that if that restriction is lifted then you can pass that as an argument to the constructor (which can be templated and deduce the proper type).

Comment: @user905927: There are other interesting questions, as how do you intend on using this type in your code base? That is, **what is the actual problem to solve?** You should ask about the problem to solve, rather than the solution you thought. There might be simpler approaches to what you are doing.

Comment: @David: I went with that reasoning too at first, but discovered that OP wants to handle any string type, so you need to specify it in the template arguments to the `option_string` class (the `option_string` member that holds the member pointer needs a specific type even before the constructor). That's why I went the route of `make_option_string`.

Comment: @Xeo: My problem is that I still don't quite get what the OP **really** wants to do. I.e. why does he need this to work as in his example above... The whole `option_string` taking a pointer to member that returns a `string`... Is this a wrapper to access members through an external interface (although the pointer being part of the type means that the wrapper is tailored to the specific member of the specific type... little use for a wrapper...)